# Узнать количество комбинаций

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Как можно узнать количество упорядоченных троек чисел `(a, b, c)` таких что

- a, b, c ∈ [0, N]
- a + b + c = N

И также интересно решение для векторов произвольной размерности `k`

Comment: Посмотрите стр. 454-455 и несколько следующих в томе 4А "Искусства программирования" Кнута. Там приводятся определенные рекуррентные соотношения...

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая [рекуррентная формула](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) для числа разбиений `n` на ровно `k` частей:

```
P(n, k) = P(n-1, k-1) + P(n-k, k)
```

На Питоне:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(1000)
def numpartitionsintokparts(n, k):
    if n < k:
        return 0
    if n == k:
        return 1
    if k == 1:
        return 1
    return numpartitionsintokparts(n-1, k-1) + numpartitionsintokparts(n-k, k)

print(numpartitionsintokparts(120, 3))

>>> 1200
```

Для конкретного случая `k=3` последовательность вызовов сводится к сумме

```
Sum((n-1-3*i)//2) + 1 if n%3==0
```

и

```
def num3(n):
    res = 1 if n%3==0 else 0
    i = n - 1
    while i >= 3:
        res += i//2
        i -= 3
    return res
```

В принципе, Sum есть сложение сумм двух арифметических (для четных и нечетных) прогрессий, так что можно и формулу получить.

upd: [уже получили](http://oeis.org/A001399):

```
def num33(n):
    return (n*n+4)//12
```